# Tensor division precision error

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am using [@tensorflow/tfjs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs) (v0.10.3) on node (v10.0.0) and I get the following output with simple arithmetic operations

```
> import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs'

> tf.print(tf.tensor1d([10]).div(tf.scalar(3)))
Tensor
    [3.3333333]

> tf.tensor1d([10]).div(tf.scalar(3)).get(0)
3.3333332538604736

> 10 / 3
3.3333333333333335
```

Why is it possible to obtain different results in a simple division?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely tensorflow is using 32 bit floats to store the values, but these are converted back to 64 bit floats by javascript, as floats in javascript are [always 64 bit](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-terms-and-definitions-number-value).

As an example, consider the following in Python:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.float32(10.0)
b = np.float32(3.0)
print(a/b)

> 3.3333333

print(np.float64(a/b))

> 3.3333332538604736

a = np.float64(10.0)
b = np.float64(3.0)
print(a/b)

> 3.3333333333333335
```